# How to find the number of pills from an assorted group taken at the end of a treatment?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, word-problem

The problem is as follows:

> Mike takes exactly each $6$ hours the following pills: $2$ of type
> $A$, $3$ of type $B$ and $4$ of type $C$. He began taking his
> treatment taking the three kinds of pills and finished when the sum of
> the amount from the pills of type $B$ and type $C$ was $42$. Find how
> many pills of type $A$, Mike took in total.

The alternatives given are as follows:

$\begin{array}{ll}
1.&14\\
2.&18\\
3.&12\\
4.&16\\
5.&10\\
\end{array}$

In this problem I'm totally lost as, because I'm confused exactly how should I account for the number of pills from type $A$. How can this be accounted?.

Can this be solved in an equation?. I'm confused at how to use the information of the time given in this problem, so an answer that would help me is one which may explain this part.

Comment: You can say, that Mike take  7 B and C pills in 6 hours. That means that Mike take 42 B-C-pills in 36 hours ($=\frac{42}7\cdot 6$). How many A-pills then does Mike take in 36 hours?

Comment: @callculus I don't understand. How did you get the fraction which you had put in your previous comment?. I'm assuming that $3+4=7$ so in $6$ hours he has taken those. Then in 36 hours 6 times 6 then is $42$ pills right?. But that's where I'm still stuck. Why is it $\frac{42}{7}\cdot 6$?. Can you please further help?. I'm assuming that if the treatment ends when he gets $42$ pills of $B-C$ which happens when $36$ hours have elapsed then $\frac{2}{6}\times 36=12$. Thus it would be $12$ of $A$?. Am I understanding correctly?.

Comment: Any reply, chris?

Comment: @callculus I'm sorry, my health is not good. I'm recovering from infection. Yes I read to your answer and I have replied back to it in the bottom.

Comment: Glad to hear that you are fine now.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is pretty much already given in the comments.

Each time Mike takes $3$ B and $4$ C pills. Lets say that he has take the $42$ B and C pills after n times. This means that $3n+4n=42$. Follows that he needs $n=6$ times to take the $42$ B and C pills. So he would have taken $6\times 2$ A pills.

Answer (score 0):

> Then in 36 hours $6$ times $6$ then is $42$ pills right?. But that's
> where I'm still stuck. ?

As you said: "*I'm assuming that $3+4=7$ so in $6$ hours he has taken those.*" That´s right. $7$ pills ($B,C$) in $6$ hours. Now multiplying both numbers by $6$ gives $42$ pills in $36$ hours. Or you can look at these relations:

$$7 \textrm{ pills ($B,C$)} \ \hat = \ 6 \textrm{ hours} \\  42 \textrm{ pills ($B,C$)} \  \hat   = \ x  \textrm{ hours}$$

Applying rule of three gives $x=6\cdot \frac{42}{7}=6\cdot 6=36 \  \color{grey}{ \textrm{hours}}$

And in $36$ hours you can take $36 \  \color{black}{ \textrm{hours}}\cdot \frac{2 \ \color{black}{ \textrm{pills A}}}{6 \ \color{black}{ \textrm{hours}}}=12 \ \color{black}{ \textrm{pills A}}$

Comment: Thanks for adding your answer. Initially I felt dumbfounded because I didn't know how did you obtained those $\textrm{7 pills}$ it took me time to realize that you just added them up. I thought that this specific problem required something more ellaborate to be solved. It was just a matter of conversion factors and that was it. I am wondering, what if the number of both pills had not been divisible by $7$ i.e $43$?. Could this problem still had an answer?. I mean did the procedure you indicated still applied?. Can you help me with these doubts?.

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell You can still apply the rule of three: It needs $6\cdot 43/7$ hours to take $43$ B,C-pills.. So no problem up to here. But in $36$ hours Mike take $6\cdot 43/7\cdot \frac26$ A-pills. That is not possible till the number of pills must be an integer.